# How to configure sendmail correctly?

Tags: 16.04, server, sendmail

I need to send emails by a PHP script.

I have removed Postfix and configured sendmail, but I am getting too problems.

When I execute the next command:

```
 test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && test -x /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail && test -x /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
```

I see this message

```
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
```

What can I do?

Comment: Look like you didn't configure the sendmail smarthost relay.

Comment: Sorry, how can I do it??

Comment: How did you configure sendmail ?

Comment: With this tutorial https://www.abeautifulsite.net/configuring-sendmail-on-ubuntu-1404

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was a strange message in /var/spool/mqueue-client, every time sendmail tried to flush its queue it got nervous about it and returned an error.
How this message arrived and why it was starving in the queue is unclear to me. I simply removed the suspicious message and the system went well.

In mail.log following is seen:

```
Sep 27 12:42:55 host sm-msp-queue[24233]: v8QIL1mk013002: SYSERR(root): timeout writing message to [127.0.0.1]
Sep 27 12:42:55 host sm-mta[24234]: v8RAglIV024234: collect: premature EOM: unexpected close
```

Tip: to see message lurking around use the command `mailq`